# best way to send files to GCS with Django

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-storage

what is the best way to send files to Google cloud storage with django.

this moment I'm getting the file with a post method

```
file = request.FILES['image']
```

but when I try to send to GCS

```
    from google.cloud import storage
    client = storage.Client(projectName)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucketName)
    blob = bucket.blob(fileName)
    blob.upload_from_filename(file)
```

I get this erros `InMemoryUploadedFile` so I have to save the file in a temp and after that send to GCS, but it is slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error may be because of incorrect use of **fileName** and **file**. Try sync streaming of the file with upload request, like this :

```
from google.cloud import storage

def upload_file(file,projectName,bucketName, fileName, content_type):

    client = storage.Client(projectName)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucketName)
    blob = bucket.blob(fileName)

    blob.upload_from_string(
        file,
        content_type=content_type)

    url = blob.public_url
    if isinstance(url, six.binary_type):
        url = url.decode('utf-8')

    return url
```

For further reading, [Reference.](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 3):

This how I uploaded file via djano,
below shows the view method from my django(drf) view

```
def upload_gcp(self, request):
  file = request.data["file"]
  storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(
        'path-to-credentials-file.json'
    )
  bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("sandbox-bucket-001")
  blob = bucket.blob(file.name)
  blob.upload_from_string(file.file.read())
```

The file was sent as formdata and in this case, the uploaded file is contained in the key named `file` and the `file` python variable is the `InMemoryUploadedFile` object and `file.name` contains the actual name of the uploaded file

Answer (score 0):

#Looks like above methods are not working. I did something in this way

```
file_info= request.FILES['file']
bucket = storage_object.get_bucke`enter code here`t('bucket-name')
blob = bucket.blob('filename')
blob.upload_from_file(file_info.file, content_type='image/jpeg', 
rewind=True)
```